# @Value isn't replace by placeholder in test

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, junit

I am in an spring boot application. I want to make some unit test and use a properties file into src/test/resources.

Attributes with `@Value` annotation isn't fill by the property value.

I tried to add `<testResources>` into the pom but it doesn't work.
I tried to add `*` after classpath keyword in `@PropertySource` but it doesn't work too.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class UnitTestConfiguration {

}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UnitTestConfiguration.class})
class AccountsControllerTest {

    @Value("${web-client-factory.valid-jwt}")
    public String validJwt; // null in debug
}
```

I expect an exception if spring didn't find the properties but it just do nothing and my attribute is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use : `@TestPropertySource(locations={"application-test.properties"})`

Comment: i have try to change @PropertySource by @TestPropertySource(locations={"application-test.properties"}) and it didn't work :s The validJWT attribute is still null

Comment: Try to add @SpringBootTest to AccountsControllerTest and tell if it work !

Comment: Something different happen, my attribute is equal to my key "${web-client-factory.valid-jwt}". i need to enable properties no ?

Comment: Ohh i had that in my minde but i am too late :( because your properties look like application-{profile}.properties